# Cryptic TFS Build Error - Bug?

Tags: build, tfs, continuous-integration

Can anyone make any sense of this TFS build error? Googling produces few results and my research hasn't given me a solution.

> Method not found: 'Void
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.ModuleCoverage.set_Statistics(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.CoverageStatistics)'.

For a previous build, where I was getting this same error, I changed `Analyze Test Impact` to `False`, and then the build worked. That's not working here though.

What does this even mean? Is it a bug? Does anyone know how to fix it?

My attempt at fixing the issue:

[image: My attempt at fixing the issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the error shown in the original question wasn't really the problem. We have now fixed this in two different solutions, two different ways.

In the first solution, the build succeeded by fixing the CA errors.

In the second solution, the build succeeded by fixing syntax in a post-build event.

I think the entire problem is that an error was showing that wasn't really the problem. I'm not sure why that `method not found` error would be the symptom, but it wasn't the cause.

Actually, that `method not found` error still shows in the build log, but the build succeeds, so sometimes you just have to move on...

Answer (score 2):

I did not get this exact error, but I got a similar error where built in methods were failing because of the wrong signature and missing methods, because someone installed Visual Studio 2012 on one of my servers. My guess is the new TFS Dlls that came with 2012 were GAC'd and took precedence over the 2010 dlls. I would verify this hasn't happened to you as well.

Comment: Sorry Bob, Good Luck figuring it out

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error in the webview but not in the build log file and the build was not failing. Applying the TFS 2010 SP1 patch fixed it for me.